# Отправка письма php фоном

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Задача следующая. Нужно по нажатию кнопки на странице, собрать все заполненные пользователем поля и отправить их на конкретный email, при этом не открывать новых страниц. Остаться в той же точке скролла, в которой пользователь и был. Проще говоря, провернуть всё фоном, вывести ему сообщение об успешной отправке, 
ну и в идеале заблокировать кнопку отправить, но это уже мелочи.

Понятно, что нужно использовать html тэг form. Интересует именно php часть.
Понимаю, что вопрос большой, но я прошарил всё, что смог, но не нашел ответ.
Буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Средствами чистого PHP тут не обойтись. Копайте в сторону AJAX`a.
На примере jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "URL",
    data: $("#yourForm").serialize(),
    beforeSend: function(){
        //Блокируем кнопку
    },
    success: function(msg){
        if(msg == "OK"){ 
            // Делаем что-то с кнопкой
        }
    }
});
```

В PHP на уже другой странице обрабатывается и выводится ОК.

Comment: Прочитать про ajax можно здесь http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-запрос

Comment: *Интересует именно php часть*. Ваш ответ лишь частично отвечает на вопрос, для полноценного ответа не хватает примера отправки почты на php.

Comment: @Alex , вместо Вас никто готовый код писать не будет. Дадут только направление. Даже "нубских" знаний должно хватить, чтобы написать php скрипт отправки сообщений. Читайте [mail PHP](https://phpclub.ru/detail/article/mail)

Comment: *вместо Вас никто готовый код писать не будет.* - Вы верно адресом ошиблись, подразумевалось, что Ваш ответ больше тянет на комментарий нежели чем на ответ. Возможно Вам стоит ознакомиться со справкой **[как написать хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Вы явно путаете сайт а-ля форум и сообщество so. И если Вы считаете вопрос очень простым, что помешало Вам уделить 5 минут и написать полный ответ? Судя по тому как задан вопрос Ваш ответ мало поможет автору(если конечно под php он не имел ввиду ajax запрос).